# How to Make Canvas Text Appear and Disappear in Tkinter Using .after

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

How would you make a canvas.create_text disappear after a certain amount of time?

```
def showLabel1():
    loadingtext1 = canvas.create_text(500, 475)
    canvas.itemconfig(loadingtext1, text='Uploading Packages',font=("COURIER", 10))

    window.after(1500, ?????????)
window.after(500, showLabel1)
```

I know destroy or forget doesn't work because it is not a label.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `delete` method of Canvas

```
def showLabel1():
    loadingtext1 = canvas.create_text(500, 475)
    canvas.itemconfig(loadingtext1, text='Uploading Packages',font=("COURIER", 10))
    window.after(1500, lambda: canvas.delete(loadingtext1))
```

Comment: Yup.  Can't believe I missed that!